# only id(String), alias(Provider), or alias( Provider Convertible) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

Tags: android, kotlin

I got this error after copy/paste some lines in the plugins {} block, those lines add some kotlin features, like this

```
    id: 'kotlin-android'
```

then I got the title error

I checked the code but it seems ok

Answer (score 3):

As a primer, Gradle build scripts are generally either defined in Groovy (as `build.gradle`), or Kotlin (as `build.gradle.kts`). As you're using single-quotes (which Kotlin does not allow for non-characters), I'll presume that you're using Groovy.

---

The reason why you're encountering the issue you're facing is because [`x: y` syntax in Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_maps) generally translates to creating a `Map` in Java:

```
abc: "def"
```

(should be the same as)

```
mapOf("abc" to "def")
```

While the `plugins` block generally expects plugins to be defined as calls to the [`id`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html#id-java.lang.String-) or [`alias`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html#alias-org.gradle.api.provider.Provider-) **methods**:

```
plugins {
  id("java") // Include the built-in Java plugin
  alias(libs.plugins.example) // Include a plugin defined from a version catalog
  id("com.example.plugin") version "1.2.3" // Include a 3rd-party "com.example.plugin" plugin at version 1.2.3
}
```

Note that parentheses are [considered as optional in Groovy for method calls](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_optional_parentheses), hence why you may see them omitted in documentation, or as you referenced in your answer:

```
plugins {
  id 'kotlin-android' // Note the missing parentheses, and Groovy allows for single-quotes to be used too
}
```

---

For more info, see the [plugins DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block).

Comment: Thanks but can you explain me how groovy is related to my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved removing the colon from the lines, like this:

```
    id 'kotlin-android'
```